# Regex for positive integers separated by abritrary space

Tags: c#, regex

**Example input:** `"  1  4 2 5 9 "`

**Wanted:** `"1"`, `"4"`, `"2"`, `"5"`, `"9"`

Use like

```
var rgx = new Regex("???"); 
var matches = rgx.Matches("  1  4 2 5 9 ");
var nums = new List<int>();
foreach(var match in matches)
    nums.Add(match.Caputre.Value);
```

Comment: Why regex? Do the strings always consist of digit chunks and whitespace only?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If you have a better suggestion than using regex here, please let me know. Simply, what I need is to parse integers out of a string of integers separated by arbitrary amounts of whitespace.

Comment: Do you mean any whitespace or literal spaces (as your example shows)?

Comment: Literal space, I guess

Comment: Split() on " " with StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries set?

Comment: Are they always single digits? If so you could do something like: "  1 2  9     3".Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).ToList();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure there are only spaces and digit chunks, you can use LINQ and parse integers with `int.Parse`:

```
var str = "  1  4 2 5 9 ";
var res = str.Split(new[] { " " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
     .Select(r => int.Parse(r))
     .ToList();
```

If you also need a kind of a pre-validation (to make sure your string only contains any whitespace and digit chunks, you may use a safer regex based solution:

```
var res2 = Regex.Matches(str, @"^(?:\s*([0-9]+))+\s*$")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .SelectMany(p => p.Groups[1].Captures.Cast<Capture>().Select(m => int.Parse(m.Value)))
    .ToList();
```

Both result in:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Split would be a slower way to do it.

Try using matches(), something like:

```
var nums = new List<int>();
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches("  1  4 2 5 9 ", @"\d+"))
{
    nums.Add(Int32.Parse(match.Value));
}

///////////////
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach (int nN in nums)
{
    builder.Append(nN).Append(",");
}
string result = builder.ToString();
Console.WriteLine("{0}", result);
```